# Using Typscript how can a create a union of filtered String literal types from an object

Tags: typescript

In the following example:

```
const cars = [
    {brand: "tesla", model:"Y", colour: "BLACK"},
    {brand: "tesla", model: "S", colour: "WHITE"},
    {brand: "hyundai", model: "Ioniq5", colour: "BLACK"},
    {brand: "hyundai", model: "Ioniq6", colour: "BLACK"},
    {brand: "rivian", model: "R1", colour: "WHITE"}
] as const
```

using the following:

```
type Brands = (typeof cars)[number]["brand"]
```

creates a type:

"tesla" | "hyundai" | "rivian"

Is it possible to create a union type that filters const cars, based on the colour (e.g. "WHITE") and create a type:

"tesla" | "rivian"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with  intersection type.

```
type Brands = ((typeof cars)[number] & { colour: "WHITE" })["brand"]
```

More general solution would be using `Extract/Exclude` utility types.

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never

type Brands = Extract<(typeof data)[number], { colour: "WHITE" }>["brand"]
```